# Rooted, encrypted Galaxy Note 8" stuck in bootloop

Tags: boot-loop, encryption, samsung-galaxy-note-8

I poked at things I shouldn't have after rooting/encrypting my Galaxy Note 8" tablet (GT-N5110) and now it continuously loops through the bootup screen.  It gives me just enough time to see the "enter passcode to decrypt" screen after the Samsung logo, then it re-boots.

This is a tablet, so no battery removal. I hadn't flashed any custom ROMs (except adding ClockworkMod recovery), only rooted and encrypted the device. I accidentally erased the wrong thing when messing with a debloater app, which is why I am now stuck in a boot loop on an encrypted device. No fastboot option, only ClockworkMod--which can't help because of encryption.

I have ClockworkMod installed, but I still can't factory reset since I can't unlock the encryption.

Help?

Comment: It's for a different device, but see if this XDA post will help: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=20479867&postcount=24 In summary, you can flash a ROM via fastboot; it might work. Can't check the google link there; it's blocked from my end.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the site anymore after posting the question, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Things to try

- I'd say take off the batteries, put them back, go to download mode, and reflash the ROM. Better off download it again to be 100% certain it's OK (even if it is, sometimes certain ROMs happen to work only after a couple times flashing).
- Also read the documentation of the ROM in case it needed your storage to be in a different filesystem format (ext4 or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Odin 3.09 *Specifically*
2. Find stock firmware
   (I use sammobile.com)
3. Try factory Dongle to force odin donwload mode (If you cant get into download mode)
4. flash